# Angularjs simple meaning of module and Dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am New to angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('ProductController', ['$scope,$htttp', productController]);
```

Please correct me if i am wrong

This above two line is saying we have created the module name app
and we have controller called productController and have $scope, $http as a dependency.
App is starting point of our angularjs application.
Controller is basically for business logic.
what is the servieces ,Factory ?
what is Dependency Injection in simple words ? 
I want to understand it more clearly as i study on angualar.js also. but unable to understand it clearly.

Please help to provide me some simple understanding on this

Comment: SO is not a substitute for a tutorial. Wanting to understand all the fundamentals of Angular v1.x (i.e. services, factory, dependency injection) is fine, but too broad for a question on SO

Comment: this type of question will get a bad response. plus you have a typo in your code. its not htttp > its http

Comment: Take online course for better understanding of angular, for example this one http://www.lynda.com/AngularJS-tutorials/Up-Running-AngularJS/154414-2.html

Comment: yes its my spell mistake sorry for that . and if it is too broad for SO, can u only give me simple explaination on this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.module` create module for application, and an application can one or more than one module. It's for modularity. so if you want to initialize core module. then you have to

```
var app=angular.module("core.module", [
      /* Shared Modules */
        "services",
        "widgets",
        "layout"])
```

So what it does it will initialize every module for application.so by using `app` object you can directly create common directive for all the modules and much more.

```
core.module is behaves like constructor and what you want to initialize will pass in "[]" during the call of constructor. it's up-to you.
```

You can call it as dependency.

In every module you can have different controllers but one thing always keep in mind whenever you add script file reference in html then do add child modules first then core otherwise it will give error. Module not defined.

Service and Factory pretty much they both are equivalent. Most important is to realize that both are singletons.

Factories are functions that return the object, while services are constructor functions of the object which are instantiated with the new keyword.

Services:

```
angular.module('app').service('abcservice', function() {
    this.getdata= function() {};
});
```

Factory:

```
 angular.module('app').factory('TestFactory', function() {
    return {
        someFunction: function() {}
    };
});
```

when you want to use services and factory in our application then you have to pass it as argument/dependency in controller declaration.

```
 app.controller(controllerId, ['$scope','abcservice','TestFactory']);
```

For much please refer [Angular Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)